# Event for Back navigation in browser using script

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I need to know whether user clicked the back navigation arrow in browser. I Used the below event but not occur this event while i am clicking the back navigation arrow.

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {

});
```

please suggest your answer If you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the popstate of the history.

> The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as clicking on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript). And the event is only triggered when the user navigates between two history entries for the same document.

You'll have to add a new entry to history with the same title and no change to the url

```
pushState(state, title, url)
```

and when you intercept the onpopstate you will do your desired actions, unbind the event and then use the history.back() api.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
  window.onpopstate = null;
  history.back();
};

history.pushState({}, document.title, "");
```

This is not a proven method I've tested it just in Chrome.

Comment: please thank me using the the top arrow  of my answer (this answer is useful)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't.

Long answer - yoooooooooooouuuuuuuuuu caaaaaaaaannnnnnnnnn't.

At least not in the way that I think you're looking for. Best you can do is detect when user is leaving the page - though that doesn't necessarily mean that the back button was clicked. Also, you *can't stop them leaving the page*.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Leave this page?';
};
```

Using the onbeforeunload event, you can run some arbitrary code - but the browser will show a modal dialog box asking the user whether they want to leave the page or remain on the page. *You can't override this*.